# Corrosion on pipe?

Tags: leak, radiator, corrosion, copper-pipe

This section of pipe has looked the same for a few years (perhaps the whole time I’ve lived here)Never seen visible leak or dampness. So am not sure if this is a leak or impending leak……does this warrant a plumber visit to replace section of pipe?

Thanks all. Much appreciated.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the flux from soldering was not cleaned off throughly, and then the pipe was painted.

Scrub it clean (which will take poorly attached paint) and possibly use a bit of sodium bicarbonate to neutralize any remaining excess acid from the flux, then rinse, then (if desired) repaint (or don't if not desired.)

No plumber should be required.